# Can't click any UI element in Touch UI mode

Tags: html, aem

I am using AEM6.1 to develop components, and I found that in Touch UI edit mode, after I completing a dialog's configuration and generate the html element, I can't click any element in the html element in Touch UI mode.

For example:
I can't click the image in the carousel under TouchUI edit mode, but in others modes after I click the image, it will redirect to another.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

from your image, It is classicUI - editMode. it's not touchUI.
you cannot click on that in editMode. It's wrapped by coralUI in editMode for editing purpose. switch it to disabledMode then you can click

In TouchUI:

- disabledMode: http://localhost:4502/content/geometrixx/en.html?wcmmode=disabled
- EditMode: http://localhost:4502/editor.html/content/geometrixx/en.html?wcmmode=enabled (left click to configure)

In ClassicUI:

- disabledMode:
  http://localhost:4502/cf#/content/geometrixx/en.html?wcmmode=disabled
- EditMode: 
  http://localhost:4502/cf#/content/geometrixx/en.html?wcmmode=enabled (right click to configure if your component doesnot contain Editbar like your image. otherwise you can click on editbar to configure)

Comment: Sorry, I post a wrong image. And I think you have misunderstood my meaning. Could you tell me, if you can click the image or the white points in the carousel under Touch UI disabledMode? And how it is in ClassicUI disabledMode?

Comment: ya, I'm able to click on the image and the white pagination dots in disabledMode (both TouchUI & ClassicUI. in classic UI, you can click on preview icon in sidekick to switch to disabledMode). It could be your AEM instance problem, try to reinstall AEM instance.

Comment: You mean that, when you click the image and it will jump to another page in TouchUI editMode? Actually, I don't care how it is in classicUI both disabledMode and EditMode)? If so, could you please tell me which device are you using? I'm using laptop and its operating system is windows 7 to author pages. I have test it in many instances, they are all the same.